# Changing placeholder text when window resizes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery, how can I change the placeholder text to a textarea when a user is on a small device (~320px and less)? I want it to change to "Reply..." for small screens, but anything greater than 320px, it reverts back to "Reply to [name]..."

Currently, my HTML:

```
<textarea class="my_textarea" rows="1" type="text" placeholder="Reply to Joe..."></textarea>
<textarea class="my_textarea" rows="1" type="text" placeholder="Reply to Jane..."></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
function changePlaceholder() {
    if( $(window).width() < 320 ){
        $('.my_textarea').attr('placeholder','Reply...');
    } else {
      // how do I change it back here if there are many textarea's on the page?
    }   
}

// initiate first
changePlaceholder();

// resize
$(window).resize( changePlaceholder );
```

How can I revert back to the original placeholder?

Comment: Add an `else` clause and change it back?

Comment: If there are many textarea's on the page, how do I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first store all the different placeholders so you can get them back:

```
$('.my_textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
});

function changePlaceholder() {
    if( $(window).width() < 320 ){
        $('.my_textarea').attr('placeholder','Reply...');
    } else {
        $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
        });
    }   
}

$(window).resize( changePlaceholder ).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: would it not make more sense to store it an a property, rather then a data attribute? I was thought that you should change the DOM as little as possible. And I think it would be useful to check if the placeholder attribute needs changing, or already contains the correct value.

Comment: @PeterVR - jQuery's `data()` will not change the DOM, it will store the original placeholder internally as a property.

Comment: I always thought it would add an actual data-placeholder attribute, as it is the same syntax used for reading these attributes. My bad!

Comment: @PeterVR - Yes, it's confusing, but `data()` will get the value of a HTML5 data attribute if it exists, but it will not set it, you have to use `attr('data-something', 'new value')` to actually change the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues on your page

```
<textarea class="my_textarea"
```

And your selector is selecting as an **id attribute**

```
$('#my_textarea')
```

Supposed to be

```
$('.my_textarea')
```

You can use `$.each` to iterate over all the elements and set them accordingly.

Next , each `textarea` has different placeholder values. So it is a time for `HTML-5` data-* attributes.

**HTML**

```
 <textarea class="my_textarea"
              rows="1" type="text" data-placeholder="Reply to Joe..."
              placeholder="Reply to Joe..."></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function changePlaceholder() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth < 320 ) {
        $('.my_textarea').attr('placeholder','Reply...');
    }
    else {
         $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
              var that = this;
              $(this).attr('placeholder', function(_, plc) {
                    return that.data('placeholder');
              });
         });
    }
}

// initiate first
changePlaceholder();

// resize
$(window).resize( changePlaceholder );
```

Comment: Changed it to be a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to hold initial values then iterate over array.

```
var placeholderValues = [];

function changePlaceholder() {
    if( $(window).width() < 320 ){
        $('.my_textarea').attr('placeholder','Reply...');
    } else {
      $('.my_textarea').each(function(i){
           $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholderValues[i]);
       });
    }   
}

// initiate first
changePlaceholder();

//get values
$('.my_textarea').each(function(){
   placeholderValues.push($(this).attr('placeholder'));
});

// resize
$(window).resize( changePlaceholder );
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/CmaZg/

Answer (score 0):

Save the old placeholder in a data attribute, then restore it when returning

```
var shrunk = false; // Keep from repeating this when not necessary
function changePlaceholder() {
    if(!shrunk && $(window).width() < 320){
        $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.data('save-placeholder', $this.attr('placeholder'))
                 .attr('placeholder','Reply...');
        });
        shrunk = true;
    } else if (shrunk && $(window).width >= 320) {
        $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.attr('placeholder', $this.data('save-placeholder'));
        });
        shrunk = false;
    }   
}
```